# How to optimize GtkListStore from using too much memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, out-of-memory, gtk3

I'm building an offline Semitic root database program to practice MySQL and decided to use GTK3 for the GUI.

The problem I'm having is that the GtkListStore keeps crashing the program because it's allocating too much memory.

I have found that when I load the Triliteral roots, the program is fine but when I clear the liststore and load Triliteral roots again, it allocates more memory than needed.

Anyways, the question is: How can I properly free the Liststore? I've searched online countless times and couldn't find the answer so I gave up and asked here.

Below is the code for the program.

appmain.c

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <mysql/mysql.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include <glib.h>
    #include <string.h>

#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
#endif

#include "widgets.h"

/*
rootid - INT -> must be primary key = PRIMARY KEY (rootid) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
rootwords - VARCHAR(4)
rootmeanings - VARCHAR(1024)

create table syriacroots (rootid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, rootwords VARCHAR(4), rootmeanings VARCHAR(1024), PRIMARY KEY (rootid));
*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* pshaqa is Syriac-Aramaic for solution, create and allocate memory for all the data our app needs */
    struct mainApp *pshaqa = malloc( sizeof(struct mainApp) );
    if (!pshaqa) {
        printf("ERROR: main::pshaqa - **** malloc returned NULL ****\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // start up and assert connection to database.
    /* removed mysql sensitive code */
    /* create the main window */
    pshaqa->window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    setup_mainwindow(pshaqa->window);

    /* create page 1 which will handle the roots information and the listboxes */
    GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pshaqa->window), scrolledwindow);

    /* create notebook-style page control for the program */
    pshaqa->notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), pshaqa->notebook);

    GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    GtkWidget *lblRoot = gtk_label_new("Semitic Roots Control");
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(GTK_WIDGET(lblRoot), "Notebook Area that concerns modifying the Syriac Roots database.");

    /* page 2 will handle quit, about, and rebuilding the roots */
    GtkWidget *vbox2 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 1);
    GtkWidget *lblInfo = gtk_label_new("Information");
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(GTK_WIDGET(lblInfo), "Misc. Info Area to Quit the application, About the application, or Rebuild the Syriac roots list.");

    /* add the new pages to the notebook itself */
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(pshaqa->notebook), vbox, lblRoot);
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(pshaqa->notebook), vbox2, lblInfo);

    /* create list store and tree iterator */
    pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore = gtk_list_store_new(2, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    //GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    /* set up initial liststore info */
    //gtk_list_store_append(pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore, &treeiter);
    //gtk_list_store_set(pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore, &treeiter, 0, "click on roots button to set the list", 1, "", -1);

    /* setup our tree view and add it to the window */
    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore));

    /* setup the cell renderer so we can hold our text then setup the columns on the treeview */
    /*GtkCellRenderer *cellrendNum = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Root ID", cellrendNum, "text", 0, NULL);
    g_object_set(cellrendNum, "editable", TRUE, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn);
    g_signal_connect(cellrendNum, "edited", G_CALLBACK(on_idcell_edited), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);*/

    /* create and setup the Root string column */
    GtkCellRenderer *cellrendRoot = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Literal Root", cellrendRoot, "text", 0, NULL);
    //g_object_set(cellrendRoot, "editable", TRUE, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn);
    //g_signal_connect(cellrendRoot, "edited", G_CALLBACK(on_rootcell_edited), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);
    //g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-deleted", G_CALLBACK(on_row_deleted), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);

    /* create and setup the Root meaning column */
    //GtkCellRenderer *cellrendMeaning = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Meaning", cellrendRoot, "text", 1, NULL);
    g_object_set(cellrendRoot, "editable", TRUE, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), pshaqa->areaRoots.treeviewcolumn);
    g_signal_connect(cellrendRoot, "edited", G_CALLBACK(on_meaningcell_edited), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);

    /* make Biliteral Roots button */
    pshaqa->areaRoots.btnBi = gtk_button_new_with_label("Biliteral Roots");

    /* TODO: make void* array and pass the root struct along with liststore */
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnBi), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(biroots_clicked), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), pshaqa->areaRoots.btnBi, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(GTK_WIDGET(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnBi), "Button that loads the Biliteral Syriac Roots");

    /* make Trilieral roots button */
    pshaqa->areaRoots.btnTri = gtk_button_new_with_label("Triliteral Roots");
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnTri), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(triroots_clicked), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), pshaqa->areaRoots.btnTri, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(GTK_WIDGET(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnTri), "Button that loads the Triliteral Syriac Roots");

    /* make Quadliteral roots button */
    pshaqa->areaRoots.btnQuad = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quadliteral Roots");
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnQuad), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(quadroots_clicked), pshaqa->areaRoots.liststore);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), pshaqa->areaRoots.btnQuad, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(GTK_WIDGET(pshaqa->areaRoots.btnQuad), "Button that loads the Quadliteral Syriac Roots");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), treeview, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(pshaqa->window);
    gtk_main();

    if (pshaqa)
        free(pshaqa);
    pshaqa = NULL;
end:
    return 0;
}

void window_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void biroots_clicked(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data)
{
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;
    /* clear the entire listing to update for new list */
    gtk_list_store_clear(GTK_LIST_STORE(data));

    const char *atwate[] = {"ܐ","ܒ","ܓ","ܕ","ܗ","ܘ","ܙ","ܚ","ܛ","ܝ","ܟ","ܠ","ܡ","ܢ","ܣ","ܥ","ܦ","ܨ","ܩ","ܪ","ܫ","ܬ"};
    const unsigned char nloop = sizeof( atwate ) / sizeof( *atwate );

    gchar roots[5];
    unsigned char i, j;
    for (i=0; i < nloop; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < nloop; j++) {
            sprintf(roots, "%s%s", atwate[i], atwate[j]);
            gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter);
            gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter, 0, roots, 1, "", -1);
        }
    }
}
void triroots_clicked(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data)
{
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    /* clear the entire listing to update for new list */
    gtk_list_store_clear(GTK_LIST_STORE(data));

    const char *atwate[] = {"ܐ","ܒ","ܓ","ܕ","ܗ","ܘ","ܙ","ܚ","ܛ","ܝ","ܟ","ܠ","ܡ","ܢ","ܣ","ܥ","ܦ","ܨ","ܩ","ܪ","ܫ","ܬ"};
    const unsigned char nloop = sizeof( atwate ) / sizeof( *atwate );

    gchar roots[7];
    unsigned char i, j, n;
    for (i=0 ; i<nloop ; i++) {
        for (j=0 ; j<nloop ; j++) {
            for (n=0 ; n<nloop ; n++) {
                sprintf(roots, "%s%s%s", atwate[i], atwate[j], atwate[n]);
                gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter);
                gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter, 0, roots, 1, "", -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
void quadroots_clicked(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data)
{
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;
    /* clear the entire listing to update for new list */
    gtk_list_store_clear(GTK_LIST_STORE(data));

    const char *atwate[] = {"ܐ","ܒ","ܓ","ܕ","ܗ","ܘ","ܙ","ܚ","ܛ","ܝ","ܟ","ܠ","ܡ","ܢ","ܣ","ܥ","ܦ","ܨ","ܩ","ܪ","ܫ","ܬ"};
    const unsigned char nloop = sizeof( atwate ) / sizeof( *atwate );

    gchar roots[9];
    unsigned char i, j, n, t;
    for (i=0 ; i<nloop ; i++) {
        for (j=0 ; j<nloop ; j++) {
            for (n=0 ; n<nloop ; n++) {
                for (t=0 ; t<nloop ; t++) {
                    sprintf(roots, "%s%s%s%s", atwate[i], atwate[j], atwate[n], atwate[t]);
                    gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter);
                    gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(data), &treeiter, 0, roots, 1, "", -1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void on_meaningcell_edited(GtkWidget *cellrenderer, gchar *path, gchar *text, gpointer data)
{
    GtkTreeModel *model = (GtkTreeModel *)data;
    GtkTreePath *treepath = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string(path);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &treeiter, treepath);

    gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &treeiter, 1, text, -1);
}

void on_row_deleted(GtkTreeModel *tree_model, GtkTreePath *path, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (path)
        gtk_tree_path_free(path);
    path = NULL;
}

void setup_mainwindow(GtkWidget *x)
{
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(x), 800, 300);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(x), "Syriac Database Program");
    g_signal_connect(x, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(window_destroy), NULL);
}
```

widgets.h

```
#ifndef WIDGETSZ
    #define WIDGETSZ

#ifdef __linux__
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
#endif

struct root {
    unsigned int iID;
    char strRoot[5];        // size in database = 4
    char *strMeaning;       // size in database = 1024
};

struct page1 {
    GtkWidget
        *btnBi,
        *btnTri,
        *btnQuad
    ;
    GtkListStore        *liststore;
    GtkTreeViewColumn   *treeviewcolumn;
};

struct page2 {
    GtkWidget *btnQuit, *btnAbout, *btnRebuild;
};

struct mainApp {
    GtkWidget
        *aboutdialog,
        *window,
        *treeview,
        *notebook
    ;
    struct page1    areaRoots;
    struct page2    areaInfo;
};


/* callback funcs */
void window_destroy(GtkWidget*, gpointer);
void biroots_clicked(GtkWidget*, gpointer);
void triroots_clicked(GtkWidget*, gpointer);
void quadroots_clicked(GtkWidget*, gpointer);
//void on_idcell_edited(GtkWidget*, gchar*, gchar*, gpointer);
//void on_rootcell_edited(GtkWidget*, gchar*, gchar*, gpointer);
void on_meaningcell_edited(GtkWidget*, gchar*, gchar*, gpointer);
void on_row_deleted(GtkTreeModel*, GtkTreePath*, gpointer);


/* Widget setup funcs */
void setup_mainwindow(GtkWidget*);

#endif /* WIDGETSZ */
```